# How to save data from python into a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I've got a program that on the end prints a "match" I wanted to save the data in this "match" to a csv file, how can I do that? I've wrote some code, to save this variable, but it doesn't write anything
Here's my code:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import pickle
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print('Current working directory is '+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs')
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, " "))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()

def run(command):
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        args = shlex.split(command)
    else:
        args = command
    s = subprocess.Popen(args,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = s.communicate()
    return s.returncode == 0, output, errors

# Change this to your PDF file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs'
if not os.path.isdir(base_directory):
    print "%s is not a directory" % base_directory
    exit(1)
# Change this to your pdf2htmlEX executable location
bin_path = 'C:\\Python27\\pdfminer-20140328\\tools\\pdf2txt.py'
if not os.path.isfile(bin_path):
    print "Could not find %s" % bin_path
    exit(1)
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a PDF file
        if not file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        # Convert your PDF to HTML here
        args = (bin_path, file_name, file_path)
        success, output, errors = run("python %s -o %s.html %s " %args)
        if not success:
            print "Could not convert %s to HTML" % file_path
            print "%s" % errors
htmls_path = 'C:\\PROJECT'
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(htmls_path):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        if not file_name.endswith('.html'):
            continue
        with open(file_name) as markup:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
            text = soup.get_text()
            match = re.findall("PA/(\S*)\s*(\S*)", text)
            print(match)
with open ('score.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows('%s' %match)
```

The part where I tried to save it into a csv file is the last 3 lines of code.
Here's a print of the "match" format: https://gyazo.com/930f9dad12109bc50825c91b51fb31f3

Comment: Please read [ask] and possibly provide a [mcve], as in the current state the answer neither gives an exact description of the result you expect (format, ...) nor shows your own effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Are the last 3 lines indented here the same way as your file ? If so, I guess the problem lies there.

Comment: yeah they are, should I tab them?

Comment: Unlike most other languages, Python uses indentation to delimit blocks. So those 3 lines are not part of the `for` loop. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way your code is structured, you iterate over the matches in your for loop, then, when the loop is finished, you save the last match in your CSV. You probably want to write each match in your CSV instead, inside the `for` loop.

try to replace the last lines of your code (starting at the last `for` loop) by:

```
with open('score.csv', 'wt') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(htmls_path):
        for file_name in file_name_list:
            if not file_name.endswith('.html'):
                continue
            with open(file_name) as markup:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
                text = soup.get_text()
                match = re.findall("PA/(\S*)\s*(\S*)", text)
                print(match)
                writer.writerow(match)
```

Comment: Ok, it saved, but it saved on a single column instead of doing like if it was a table

Comment: should be fixed now, use `match.groups()` to get the matched groups as a list.

Comment: It returned an error :  https://gyazo.com/dae08c866b8a453eb523803913ba27c7 here's it

Comment: oops you use `re.findall()` which already returns a list. edited. Also when you have a text output you can copy paste it here directly instead of taking a screenshot and post it on an external site.

Comment: Now it prints in a single line, isn't it possible to separate them in columns, like wherever is a " , " goes to a new column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your "match", you can use the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in Python. The writer should get your job done.

It would be more helpful if you could elaborate on the format of your data.

Comment: Here's a print of the "match" format : https://gyazo.com/930f9dad12109bc50825c91b51fb31f3